# Grammar of: "I'll make you sorry you did this"

Tags: grammar

> I'll make you sorry you did this.

Is this any kind of idiom? I think it should be like "I'll make you sorry for what you did", but either cases give tons of Google search results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pretty common idiom, yes, but it's actually not too ungrammatical either.  The grammatically correct way to say it really just needs one more word:

> I'll make you sorry **that** you did this

Your alternate form, "I'll make you sorry for what you did" is also fine.  The two mean pretty much the same thing, but technically "sorry that *some thing happened*" is talking about a specific event, whereas "sorry for *something*" is talking about an enduring condition.

In this case, they're pretty similar, though "sorry for what you did" could actually be referring to multiple things that were done (maybe a history of repeatedly doing bad things), whereas "sorry that you did this" is much more specifically talking about "this" one specific thing that was done being what you'll be sorry for.

Comment: It's just as grammatical without *that* as with it. Whether you include it or not is purely a matter of style, not of syntax or semantics.